# Action Script 3.0 : parsing json data

Tags: actionscript-3, json

I want to parse the json data [shown in this link](https://graph.facebook.com/barackobama/feed?access_token=221434461217388%7CZrl9EBH9aD8ZbI8XdXh0oM_ZSfI) in AS3 to obtain the "message" field . I am trying with
as3corelib.swc with no success. The json data seems to be bit different . Please help me to parse this

I am using the below code

```
var j:Object = JSON.decode(Json_data);
    var message:String = j["message"];
    trace(message);
```

Here trace always showing null

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? How are you parsing? Please show us some code. Otherwise it's difficult to guess the problem.

Comment: @ taskinoor Hi I have attached code . I am very new to As3 . please guide me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `message` under root object. Probably you are looking for this:

```
var j:Object = JSON.decode(str);
var data:Array = j["data"];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    trace(data[i].message);
}
```